# Update and Delete documents from two different collections on single click

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app like olx, Where if you upload ad , its gets posted in two different collections, namly "My Ads" where ads of every  logged in user are posted against his ID, and Explore collection Where ads are posted for all users. So if i want to update or delete ad, It should be deleted from both collections! Image Url :https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeIXM.jpg

String uid= user.getUid();
                SellingDetails.put("uid",uid);

```
            final CollectionReference reference = exploreAdDB.collection("cities/" + city + "/" + category);
            final CollectionReference myAdDocRef = myAdDB.collection("users/ads/"+uid);
            if (imageUri != null) {
                final StorageReference fileReference = mStorage.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
                UploadTask uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);
                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                            if(downloadUri!=null)
                                SellingDetails.put("imageUrl",downloadUri.toString());
                            reference.add(SellingDetails).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Toast.makeText(GetLocationActivity.this, "Service Uploaded in explore db ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pgAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(GetLocationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    Toast.makeText(GetLocationActivity.this, "Ad posted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(GetLocationActivity.this, "Failed adding data into explore db", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pgAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                            myAdDocRef.add(SellingDetails).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                    Toast.makeText(GetLocationActivity.this, "Data Also added to myAds db", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(GetLocationActivity.this, "Data not added into my ads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    });


                        } else {
                            // Handle failures
                            Toast.makeText(GetLocationActivity.this, "Failed adding data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });



            }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to upload/delete the adds?

Comment: im having trouble finding the ID,

Comment: @AlexMamo you are Firestore ninja , i know that !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, what id are you looking for?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JwZvED2

Comment: i have two collections , cities and users! in cities im posting ad for all users while in users , i m saving ads against each user id, now if i want to edit or delete ad , i need document ids of both ads , posted in users collection and in cities collection, Am i clear uptil now?

Comment: please watch this image uploaded on imgur : https://imgur.com/a/JwZvED2

Comment: Where in your cities and users collection is the uid?

Comment: no these are random documents id see https://imgur.com/a/WfoRYSj

Comment: Please provide an complete example of a documents that exist in both collections and highlight in both printscreens.